# Adding function to td table in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to js and looking for someone to help me with it. I have created javascript table with the following code:

```js
data = { players: [
  { name: 'aphra', score: 10, ping: 20 }
] };

const addRow = (el, data) => {
  if (data.players.length) {
    data.players.forEach((ply) => {

      const row = document.createElement("tr");
      row.innerHTML = `
                <td>${ply.name}</td>
                <td>${ply.score}</td>
                <td>${ply.ping == '0' ? 'BOT' : ply.ping}</td>
              `;
      el.appendChild(row);
    });
  }
};
const table = document.getElementById('id')
addRow(table, data);
```

```html
<table id="id"></table>
```

I'm trying to apply given below code function with the `<td>${ply.name}</td>` in my table js

js code function I want to apply https://jsfiddle.net/tdwcqze0/

Comment: Please fix your code so that it runs. At the moment `data` is undefined.

Comment: The function in the fiddle returns a DOM element, not HTML code. You could change it to return HTML, then you could use `${generate_colored_span(ply.name)}`. Or change this code so it creates DOM elements for the `<td>` elements instead of using `innerHTML`.

Comment: You should sanitize your strings before setting them as HTML so that nobody sets their player's name to `<img src onerror='alert()'>` or worse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

`<td>${generate_colored_span(ply.name).innerHTML}</td>`

Instead of

`<td>${ply.name}</td>`

```js
function generate_colored_span(text, className = null) {
  let cont = document.createElement('span')
  let txtary = []
  let curtxt = ''
  let curcol = '7'

  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] == '^') {
      if (curtxt) {
        curobj = {}
        curobj.txt = curtxt
        curobj.col = curcol
        txtary.push(curobj)
      }
      curtxt = ''
      i += 1
      curcol = text[i]
    } else {
      curtxt += text[i]
    }
  }
  curobj = {}
  curobj.txt = curtxt
  curobj.col = curcol
  txtary.push(curobj)

  txtary.forEach((txt) => {
    let txtsp = document.createElement('span')
    txtsp.className = 'tracker_col' + txt.col
    txtsp.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt.txt))
    cont.appendChild(txtsp)
  })
  if (className) cont.className = className
  return cont
}

const addRow = (el, data) => {
  if (data.players.length) {
    data.players.forEach((ply) => {

      const row = document.createElement("tr");
      row.innerHTML = `
                <td>${generate_colored_span(ply.name).innerHTML}</td>
                <td>${ply.score}</td>
                <td>${ply.ping == '0' ? 'BOT' : ply.ping}</td>
              `;
      el.appendChild(row);
    });
  }
};
const table = document.getElementById('id')
addRow(table, {
  players: [{
    name: 'foo',
    score: 1,
    ping: 0
  }]
});
```

```css
.tracker_col7 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="id"></table>
```